# How to make UI animation blend smoothly from the previous state when interrupted?

Tags: unity, animation, unity-ui

I have a UI that I want to animate via PointerEnter and PointerExit, but if an event gets fired while an animation is in progress, it makes the animation jump to the start point of that animation clip like so:

[image: animation issue]

I want the animation to start from where the scale was before the animation started, to get rid of that jumping issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you set up your AnimatorController (especially the transition between those two states) and show us the code you use to give instructions to it?

Comment: Do you use blend trees? I had a similar issue and "blend trees" was the solution.

Comment: @Vaillancourt I've been unable to find a suitable solution to my problem yet after a while of Google searching, so I haven't been able to try anything.